# What are the continuous points of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\cos(x))^{2n}$?

Tags: limits, continuity

For real $x$, let $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\cos(x))^{2n}$$ How to find the continuous points of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x=k\pi$, $k$ is integer,
$$cos(x)=\pm1$$
$$cos^{2}(x)=1$$

When $n\to\infty$,
$$cos^{2n}(x)=0$$
except for $x=k\pi$, $k$ is integer.

Hence $f(x)$ is continuous on $$(k\pi,(k+1)\pi)$$
$k$ is integer.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** We have $f(x)=0$ except when $x$ is of the form $k\pi$ for some integer $k$.